# Number of elements of order 4 in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, totient-function

I've read that number of elements of order 4 in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is 8, but I can't figure it out where this number come from. I now that if we're searching number of elements of order 4 in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$, we use Euler's phi function ($\phi(4)=2$). Do we use something similar here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of an element in a direct product like this one is the l.c.m of the orders inside the respective coordinates. So an element of order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ must be $1$ or $3$ in the first coordinate. In the second and third coordinate, you could have either $0$ or $1$. In each case you get elements of order $4$. There are $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8$ such possibilities.

Comment: But what about $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$? There are 12 elements of order 4.

Comment: Yes, as there should be. You will get an element that is not of order $4$ only when both the first and second coordinate do not have order $4$. For this, there are two choices ($0$ and $2$) for the first coordinate, and two choices ($0$ and $2$) for the second coordinate. So four total choices. So there are $12$ elements of order $4$.

Comment: To view it the other way, finding elements of order $4$ directly: if the first coordinate is $0$, the second coordinate must be $1$ or $3$. That's two choices. If the first coordinate is $1$, the second coordinate can be anything. That's four choices. If the first coordinate is $2$, the second coordinate must be $1$ or $3$. Two more choices. If the first coordinate is $3$, the second coordinate can be anything. Four more choices. That's $2 + 4 + 2 +4 = 12$ total choices. The reason the "multiplication" I did above doesn't work here is because above, the first coordinate had to be $1$ or $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $(a,b,c)$ is an element of order $4$. As $2b=2c=0$, $a$ has to be an element of order $4$. Therefore $a \in \{1,3\}$.

And then $b,c$ can be whatever you want. Therefore $8$ elements of order $4$.